# LaTeX Make Flow With Dashes

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

[image]

I am wondering if anyone can assist me in making this figure. I have not quite been able to set up the dashed lines over the two boxes, thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome! Questions and answers of this type exist already in rather large numbers, here is one more to give you a start. You can use `chains` for the chain of nodes on the right, and fit for the dashed rectangle.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains,fit}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=3em,
    marr/.style={-Stealth,semithick},
    cpr/.style={draw,minimum height=3.5em,inner xsep=1ex,
        text width=7em,align=center,fill=blue!20
        ,rounded corners,join,font=\sffamily}]
\begin{scope}[start chain=A going below,
    nodes={on chain,cpr},
    every join/.style={marr}]
 \node{Planning}; 
 \node{Ressources}; 
 \node{Sensors}; 
 \node{Processing}; 
\end{scope}
\node[left=of A-2,cpr] (B) {Information\\ system};
\draw[marr] (B) |- (A-1);
\draw[marr] (B) |- (A-4);
\node[draw,dashed,inner sep=1.2em,fit=(A-2)(A-3)]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]